# sssd sudenly got installed on Ubuntu 20.04!

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, boot-time, sssd

Today I was working with my fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 (about 10 days ago) and I have issued the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` commands as usual.

However, I have encountered a couple of errors and bunch dialog boxes got opened asking about sending the errors to the Ubuntu community. Then I noticed that the output of `sudo apt upgrade` is telling me that some of the packages "have been kept back".

After rebooting my system I have encountered the following errors:
[boot time sssd errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdZ4A.jpg)

I was surprised to see that SSSD have been installed on my system, I have not installed it by myself.
Then, I checked to see when the SSSD package got installed; this is the output of `grep sssd /var/log/dpkg.log`:

```
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-common:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-ad-common:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-ad-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-ad-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-krb5-common:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-krb5-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-krb5-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-ad:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-ad:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-ad:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-ipa:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-ipa:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-ipa:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-krb5:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-krb5:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-krb5:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-ldap:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-ldap:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-ldap:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-proxy:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-proxy:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-proxy:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-dbus:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-dbus:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-dbus:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 install sssd-tools:amd64 <none> 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status half-installed sssd-tools:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 10:59:17 status unpacked sssd-tools:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:47 configure sssd-common:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:47 status unpacked sssd-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:47 status half-configured sssd-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status installed sssd-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 configure sssd-proxy:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status unpacked sssd-proxy:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status half-configured sssd-proxy:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status installed sssd-proxy:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 configure sssd-dbus:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status unpacked sssd-dbus:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status half-configured sssd-dbus:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status installed sssd-dbus:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 configure sssd-ad-common:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status unpacked sssd-ad-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:52 status half-configured sssd-ad-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:53 status installed sssd-ad-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:53 configure sssd-krb5-common:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:53 status unpacked sssd-krb5-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:53 status half-configured sssd-krb5-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:53 status installed sssd-krb5-common:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:54 configure sssd-krb5:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:54 status unpacked sssd-krb5:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:54 status half-configured sssd-krb5:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:54 status installed sssd-krb5:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:54 configure sssd-ldap:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:54 status unpacked sssd-ldap:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:54 status half-configured sssd-ldap:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:54 status installed sssd-ldap:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 configure sssd-ad:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status unpacked sssd-ad:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status half-configured sssd-ad:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status installed sssd-ad:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 configure sssd-tools:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status unpacked sssd-tools:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status half-configured sssd-tools:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status installed sssd-tools:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 configure sssd-ipa:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status unpacked sssd-ipa:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status half-configured sssd-ipa:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status installed sssd-ipa:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 configure sssd:amd64 2.3.1-2 <none>
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status unpacked sssd:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status half-configured sssd:amd64 2.3.1-2
2020-10-05 11:02:55 status installed sssd:amd64 2.3.1-2
```

As you can see, the package has been installed the same morning! I don't know why.
Can anyone tell me if any other package has pulled it as a dependency or if there is a way to get rid of the boot time errors? Is it safe if I remove SSSD? if so, how can do so?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have `aptitude` installed, you could do `aptitude why sssd`.

Comment: Or you could simply uninstall it. Read your apt output carefully to see what else gets queued for uninstall.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.
I have installed `aptitude` and ran the command you have suggested. The output is the following:
`i   ubuntu-desktop-minimal Recommends sssd`
After disabling the SSSD by running `sudo systemctl disable sssd` I got rid of the errors. But now the question is, should I keep it disabled?! @OrganicMarble

Comment: @user535733 the output notifies me that `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: ldap-utils libipa-hbac0 sssd-ad sssd-ad-common sssd-ipa sssd-krb5 sssd-krb5-common sssd-ldap sssd-proxy`. What do you think?

Comment: I have noticed a new problem. I had `gnome-tweaks` installed, but now I don't see it as an installed package. When trying `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`, I get the following: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: [newline] gnome-shell (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 3.38.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed [newline] Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 3.38.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed`.